# I have an array list saved in asyncstorage with key 'list' My goal is that i need them to be rendered as picker. Items How can i do this?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

```
export default class Incomel extends Component {
    state = {
        isEdit: null,
        list: [],
        isLoading: false,
        editText: '',
    };
    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });
        // AsyncStorage.removeItem('list')
        AsyncStorage.getItem('list')
            .then(list => {
                if (list) {
                    this.setState({ list: JSON.parse(list), isLoading: false });
                } else {
                    this.setState({ list: [], isLoading: false });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({ isLoading: false });
            });
    };
    add = () => {
        let list = this.state.list;
        list.push('');
        this.setState({ list: list });
        this.saveToStorage();

        this.setEdit(list.length - 1);
    };
    setEdit = index => {
        if (this.state.isEdit !== index) {
            this.setState({ isEdit: index, editText: this.state.list[index] });
        }
    };
    setList = (text, index) => {
        let list = this.state.list;
        list[index] = text;
        this.setState({ list: list, isEdit: null, editText: '' });

        this.saveToStorage();
    };
    saveToStorage = () => {
        let data = JSON.stringify(this.state.list);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('list', data);
    };
    deleteItem = index => {
        let list = this.state.list;
        list.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({ list: list });
        this.saveToStorage();
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={style.container}>
                <View style={style.header}>
                    <Text style={style.headerText}>Incomes</Text>
                    <Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} source={require('../android/assets/1322767.png')} />

                </View>
                {this.state.isLoading ? (
                    <ActivityIndicator color="#d28888" size="large" />
                ) : (
                        <View style={style.body}>
                            {this.state.list.map((item, key) => (
                                <React.Fragment>
                                    {this.state.isEdit === null || this.state.isEdit !== key ? (
                                        <TouchableOpacity
                                            style={style.item}
                                            activeOpacity={0.5}
                                            onLongPress={() => this.setEdit(key)}>
                                            <Text style={style.itemText}>{item}</Text>
                                            <TouchableOpacity
                                                style={style.itemDelete}
                                                onPress={() => this.deleteItem(key)}>

                                                <Image style={{ width: 30, height: 30 }} source={require('../android/assets/delete-icon.png')} />
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    ) : null}
                                    {this.state.isEdit !== null ? (
                                        key == this.state.isEdit ? (
                                            <TextInput
                                                style={style.itemInput}
                                                onBlur={() => this.setList(this.state.editText, key)}
                                                onSubmitEditing={() =>
                                                    this.setList(this.state.editText, key)
                                                }
                                                value={this.state.editText}
                                                autoFocus
                                                onChangeText={editText => this.setState({ editText })}
                                            />
                                        ) : null
                                    ) : null}
                                </React.Fragment>
                            ))}
                            <TouchableOpacity style={style.btnAdd} onPress={() => this.add()}>
                                <Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} source={require('../android/assets/add-icon.png')} />

                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    )}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```